# workflow chatbot template in react.js

Tags: reactjs, chat, chatbot, flowchart

I'd like to build a chatbot model where the user constructs a tree containing the robot's responses based on the client's choices (like creating a conversation scenario between the robot and the client). It's similar to the attached image. I'd like to develop it in React, but during my research over the past month, I couldn't find libraries that assist in this matter. Please note that it's not like drawing Digrams where arrows are added automatically.[image: WorkFlow Template for Chatbot]

I tried using libraries that provide shapes like React Flow Chart, but they didn't give the desired shape, as shown in the attached image. I'm looking for a library or a third-party solution that could provide me with what I need.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean specifically by "desired shape". Are you referring to something like this: [Decision Tree Demo](https://www.yworks.com/demos/showcase/decisiontree/) ? Why doesn't React Flow work for you?

Comment: @Sebastian : We do not want the user to drag and drop, he just has to click on the plus sign to create a new level